# CSS. Не срабатывает св-во transition

Tags: html, css, transition

Есть разметка со стилями.
При помощи скрипта к классу .anim добавляется .active, что должно делать .header__item видимым и это должно происходить плавно. Скрипт никак не касается стилей. Он просто добавляет и убирает класс.
Проблема: свойство transition работает частично. Т.е. задержка, которую я устанавливаю, срабатывает, а длительность анимации не работает. Текст появляется резко и изменение значения длительности транзишена результатов не дает.

```css
    .header__list {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .header__item {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .header__link {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 127%;
    }

    .anim {
       opacity: 0;
       transition: .3s ease .5s;
    }
    
    .anim.active {
       opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="header__list">
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                            <li class="header__item anim active"><a href="#" class="header__link">Текст</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: вроде все работает - если в браузере удалять/добавлять класс `active`

Comment: В том то и дело! Вручную добавляю - работает. Автоматизирую - класс добавляет, а транзишн хромает.

Comment: как вы автоматизируете?

Comment: js-скрипт добавляет класс active, когда "айтэм" виден на экране

Comment: А где js-скрипт? Явно там проблема, потому что в CSS всё корректно

Comment: Господа, какая-то странность... вставляю скрипт сюда и все работает. Через VS Code - нифига. Подскажите, а транзишн у родительского элемента может как-то блокировать транзишн дочернего? Просто у меня этот список сидит в бургер-меню, на которое я тоже вешал транзишн.

Comment: При этом через режим разработчика в браузере показывает, что свойство применено.

Comment: нужно смотреть что у вас в бургере происходит